# Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, uwp, entity-framework-core, .net-standard, class-library

I've hit a wall when it comes to how the `Universal Windows Platform` connects/manages/interacts with a local `SQL Server` database.  My current project (`WPF using .NET Framework 4.8`) that I'm interested in porting over to `UWP` uses `EntityFramework 6` with `ADO.NET` models and it works like a charm.  No issues at all.  `UWP` on the other hand, well I'll just say that I have absolutely no idea what's going on when it comes to connecting to a local instance of `SQL Server`.  I've gone through about 3-4 different guides/templates and none have worked.  I really want to use UWP and take advantage of all the new features coming for Windows 10 v2004, but it doesn't look like this will happen.

As I currently understand the process, I need to essentially create two separate projects within the same solution.  One is the UWP main program and the other would be a .NET Core class library that targets the .NET Standard 2.0 platform.  I also have read that EntityFramework 6 is not supported on .NET Core or UWP, so the only way is by using EntityFrameworkCore (more specifically NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer).  So I installed it on the .NET Core class library and then set a reference from the UWP app to the class library.  Because the local SQL Server is already up and running, I'm not doing what is called the 'code first' approach to the creation of all the models/DbContext.cs files.  Based on what I've read, the ***ONLY*** way to import a currently existing SQL Server into the data model is by use of the Scaffold-DbContext command with a standard connection string through the package manager.  Surprisingly, this worked on the first attempt and the models and DbContext were all created without any issues.

This is about as far as I seem to be able to get as everything after does nothing but throw exceptions.  If I try to pass any C# code using the DbContext to retrieve any data from the database, I get about 10-15 exceptions that essentially say the program can't find or connect to the database.  I have manually edited the connection string in every way imaginable, but nothing seems to work.  I also tried to manually set up a new connection using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder` and `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` but they all fail with the same exceptions.

Sorry for the long post but at this point, I really don't know what's going on and would really appreciate any feedback you all could offer.

****Update 1****

So, I went back through my currently working app on .NET Framework and looked for the connection string in the `App.config` file to see what the regular EntityFramework is using and it's completely different than anything I've used before.  My guess is that it's generating a completely custom connection string that includes references to all sorts of files and a property called 'ProviderName'.  Will try cutting and pasting this string into UWP to see if it'll work.

****Update 2****

I think I'm missing something fundamental on this.  I can generate the scaffold with a connection string without any issues, but if I attempt to open a connection at runtime using the same connection string, I'm getting errors.

Comment: Hi, from your description, there seems to be a problem with the connection string. It will be helpful if you can show it (don't include private data). In addition, did you check the capability of `Enterprise Authentication` as described in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases)?

Comment: Yes, Enterprise Authentication is checked but has no effect.  What seems odd to me is that the connection string I used for the Scaffold-DbContext command doesn't work in the regular app at runtime.

Comment: The connection string that I have been using is "Data Source=**ServerName**\\SQLEXPRESS, Initial Catalog = **DatabaseName**, Integrated Security = True".  I've also tried "Server=**ServerName**, Database = **DatabaseName** but no luck with this one either.

Comment: Hi, if `Enterprise Authentication` does not work for you, you can try to check `privateNetworkClientServer`. if this is also invalid, you can tried to replace your **ServerName** with a local URL (such as 127.0.0.1,1443) (requires your SqlServer enables TCP/IP access). In debug mode, Visual Studio will remove the network loopback of the UWP application so that you can access the local network. However, when publishing, the UWP application will restrict the local network loopback, which will prevent you from accessing the local SqlServer service.

Comment: No dice with EnterpriseAuthentication and/or PrivateNetworkClientServer options checked.  For kicks, I checked all of the capability boxes and tested again.  Getting the same error message every time: "Message = "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is conf..."

Comment: Hi, if your SqlServer is built locally, have you tried to change the `ServerName` to `127.0.0.1,1443`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Richard.  Unfortunately, this also didn't work.  However, the server is not configured to allow access over TCP/IP, so that may be the problem.  On a side note, I also tried manually copying the auto-generated classes from the Class Library project directly into the UWP app in a separate namespace but this also failed.

Comment: Hi, you can try to allow the server to access via TCP/IP to see if you can connect to the server. In addition, automatically generated code usually does not require additional processing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally was able to get a connection at runtime after months of trial and error.  Without getting into too much detail, here's what worked for me (assuming EFCore has already generated a DbContext file):

1. Enable Enterprise Authentication.
2. Enable TCP/IP connections to the SQL Server instance.
3. In Visual Studio's server explorer, click Add Connection.  If you already have a connection saved for the database, right click the server and click Modify Connection
4. In the connection properties window, click the Advanced button.  Make a note of all of the listed parameters and their values and save it.
5. Open the data context file that isn't able to connect and add a using statement for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.  Now locate the OnConfiguring method.  Use a SqlConnectionStringBuilder and configure all of the parameters from the advanced connection properties that were saved earlier.

And that should work.  If there are still errors, I would double check the parameters to make sure they were all entered correctly.

Hope this post will help out anyone else dealing with this issue.